# how to step forward a simulink model programmatically

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model, I want to step forward it programatically. is there any way to do it? I tried set_param('model','SimulationCommand','step') but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to step forward it only once(to start the simulation and pause it at 0 second) SO I tried 
set_param('model','SimulationCommand','start','SimulationCommand','pause');
It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this is to run the simulation in debugging mode using `sldebug`. For more information, see [Debugging](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/debugging.html) in the Simulink documentation.